# Optimtizing an iteration

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

From Intro to Calculus & Analysis I by R. Courant and Fritz John, pg. 504:

Problem: To solve the equation x=f(x), show how best to choose the content a such that the iteration 
$$x_{k+1}=x_k+a(x_k-f(x_k))$$ converges as rapidly as possible. (EDIT: In The Neighborhood of the Solution i.e. $\xi$)

My attempt (after some discussion with my friends):

Let $\phi(x_k)=x_{k+1}$, then a solution $\xi$ to $f(x)=x$ is also a solution to $\phi(x)=x$.

By MVT, $|x_{k+1}-\xi|=|x_k-\xi||\phi'(c_k)|=|x_k-\xi||a||1+\dfrac1a-f'(c_k)|$, where $c_k$ is between $x_k$ and $\xi$. Hence, $|x_{k+1}-\xi|=|x_1-\xi||a|^k\prod
_{i=1}^k|1+\dfrac1a-f'(c_i)|$

From this point on, any attempt to progress end up being futile, almost always leading me back to where I started or giving me some really trivial result such as the absolute value of some quantity is not less than 0.

EDIT: Further Attempts:

$\forall 1\le i\le k, |1-f'(c_i)+1/a|\le |1+1/a-f'(\xi)|+|f'(\xi)-f'(c_i)|$, and if $f(x)\in C^2$ in the neighborhood of $\xi$, then there are some $\eta_1, ... , \eta_k$ such that $|f'(\xi)-f'(c_i)|=|\xi -c_i||f''(\eta_i)|$. Now since all $x_i$ is in the neighborhood of $\xi, |x_i-\xi|\lt \delta$ and also $|c_i-\xi|\le \delta$ for some fixed $\delta \gt 0$. Now, for the iteration to converge, we must have $|f'(\xi)|\le 1$ and therefore all the $|f'(c_i)|\lt 1$. Then $\dfrac{|f(c_i)-f(\xi)|}{\delta} \lt  \dfrac{|f(x_i)-f(\xi)|}{|x_i-\xi|} \lt 1$

Comment: Making this question well defined needs to make specific assumptions on the properties of $f$. If the text doesn't mention anything then maybe you have to make these assumptions on your own. Some observations: If $x*$ is an "attractive" root of the equation and our initial value is not too far away, then taking $a=-1$ (i.e, $x_{k+1} = f(x_k)$ ) is pretty good. Also, this is solving $g(x)=0$ for $g(x) = f(x)-x$. If you assume $f$ is differentiable, you can approximate $g$ around $x_k$ by a linear function and compute it's root to give you $x_{k+1}$ (this is essentially Newton's method)....

Comment: ...But if a must be constant then you can't use that as it will depend on $f'(x_k)$. I would try to prove that $a=-1$ is the constant you're looking for.

Comment: I was thinking maybe a could depend on $\xi$.

Comment: Also I would say a could depend on anything that's fixed, i.e. doesn't depend on the iteration $x_1, ... , x_k, ...$